# javascript regexp find multiple match between two string

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I write a regular expression in javascript such that it parses the string `"1.aaa 2.bbb 3.ccc"` into `["aaa","bbb","ccc"]`.

here is my code :

```js
var str = "1.aaa 2.bbb 3.ccc";
var reg1 = /\d+\.(.*)\d+\./g; //sub regexp $1 match "aaa 2.bbb"
var reg2 = /\d+\.(.*?)\d+\./g; //sub regexp $1 match "aaa"
var reg3 = /\d+\.(.*?)(?=\d+\.)/g; //sub regexp $1 match "aaa" 、 "bbb"
var reg4 = /\d+\.(.*?)(?=\d+\.)|\d+\.(.*)/g; //sub regexp $1 match "aaa" 、 "bbb"、undefined,my expect is $1 match "aaa"、“bbb”、“ccc”

str.replace(reg1, function(match, p1, p2, offset, string) {
  console.log("---reg1---")
  console.log(p1)
})

str.replace(reg2, function(match, p1, p2, offset, string) {
  console.log("---reg2---")
  console.log(p1)
})

str.replace(reg3, function(match, p1, p2, offset, string) {
  console.log("---reg3---")
  console.log(p1)
})

str.replace(reg4, function(match, p1, p2, offset, string) {
  console.log("---reg4---")
  console.log(p1) //sub regexp $1 match "aaa" 、 "bbb"、undefined,my expect is $1 match "aaa"、“bbb”、“ccc”
})
```

Is there a simple solution to do this?

Comment: Could you edit your question to explain what you are doing a little better please... I don't understand your end goal...

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a minimal code sample that shows off your efforts and tell us what you want to achieve. Improve the grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:
(Updated for second example)

```js
var s = "1.aaa 2.bbb 3.ccc";
var r = /\d+\.([^\d]*)/g;

var s2 = "1.aaa[2017-01-01] 2.bbb 3.ccc"
var s3 = "1.aaa[2017-01-01] 2.bbb[2017-01-01] 3.ccc"
var s4 = "1.aaa[2017-01-01] 2.bbb 3.ccc[2017-01-01]"
var r2 = /\d+\.(.*?)( |$)/g

function getGroups(s,r){
    var matches = [];
    var m = r.exec(s);

    while (m != null){
        matches.push(m[1]);
        m=r.exec(s);
    }
    return matches;
}
console.log(getGroups(s,r)); // ['aaa','bbb','ccc']
console.log(getGroups(s2,r2)); // [ 'aaa[2017-01-01]', 'bbb', 'ccc' ]
console.log(getGroups(s3,r2)); // [ 'aaa[2017-01-01]', 'bbb[2017-01-01]', 'ccc' ]
console.log(getGroups(s4,r2)); // [ 'aaa[2017-01-01]', 'bbb', 'ccc[2017-01-01]' ]
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression) for more info.

Comment: it also works for this example,but if the string like this:"1.aaa[2017-09-02] 2.bbb 3.ccc",how to write the regexp with [^ ]  without "/\d+\.([a-z0-9-\[\]]*)/g"

Comment: Updated. can't do the "Not Digit" group if you want to include digits.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't give much information this is the best I can come up with.

```js
var str="1.aaa 2.bbb 3.ccc";
str = '"' + str.replace(/(\d+\.)([a-z]+)/g, '$2').split(' ').join('","') + '"'

console.log(str)
```